# how to create loop for a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with 521 text files which have the gene name and the expression values. Since the gene names are common, only the expression values vary. I tried using data frames for the same but I am unable to do it. What methods can I use?

I have tried using pandas and dataframes. How can I create a loop so that only the expression values append after matching the gene name?

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('F:\study\TCGA\COAD\pcfiles\info')
f1=open('file1.txt').read().split('\n')
f2=open('file2FPKM.txt').read().split('\n')
df=pd.DataFrame(f1,f2)
print(df)
```

Output should be as follows:

```
Gene name     p1  ....................pn
gene1          x                      xn
gene2          x                      xn
gene3          x                      xn
.
.
.
.
.
gene19250      n                      xn
```

`p` is the patient's name.

`x` represents numbers.

I want all this to be written in one text file.

Comment: A hint, why don't you open each .txt file in the folder in  a for loop, read the lines, append them in your master.txt and then close master.txt once the for loop ends?

Comment: You could get more help if you were to post a sample of your data

Comment: @Hari all the 521 files have two columns. The first column is common for all the files whereas the values differs in second column. Could you tell the commands for opening all files in folder and then appending them to a master file

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

path = 'C:\\tmmp' #Directory where all .txt files stored
mastertext = open("master.txt", "a+") #Open master.txt in append mode and create one if doesn't exist in current directory
mastertext.write("header1    header2\n") #Insert the header first, assume 4 spaces between headers
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    f1=open(filename).readlines() #Open the file and read content into a list line by line
    mastertext.write(f1[1] + "\n") #Write 2nd line into master.txt (f1[1]
mastertext.close() #Close master.txt
```

For example, I have 4 text files(assume 4 spaces between each row element) as below:

**1st.txt:**

```
header1     header2
1stdata1    1stdata2
```

**2nd.txt:**

```
header1     header2
2nddata1    2nddata2
```

**3rd.txt:**

```
header1     header2
3rddata1    3rddata2
```

**4th.txt:**

```
header1     header2
4thdata1    4thdata2
```

When I run the above code, it will generate **master.txt:**

```
header1     header2
1stdata1    1stdata2
2nddata1    2nddata2
3rddata1    3rddata2
4thdata1    4thdata2
```

This might not be the best solution. Usually, if you have your files in `.csv` format, it will be much easier to process as pandas has a method `read_csv` which has an attribute `skiprows` where you can set the rows to skip, example `skiprows=0` which will skip the header. And also, since this is a `.txt` file, you may face some difficulties with the spacing between the entries in a row. In my example above, I assume a spacing of `4 space`. Have a nice day.